# Constrained linear least-squares for xA=b in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, least-squares

I want to solve `xA=b` with constraint `0<=x` for `x`.

I found functions like [lsqnonneg](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonneg.html) and [lsqlin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) which solves for `Ax=b`. However, couldn't find a good way to solve for `xA=b`.

How can I solve `xA=b` with non-negative `x` constraint?

Comment: `(xA).'=(A.')*(x.')=b.'` so you could take the transpose of your equation and use standard methods for solving `Ax=b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2917957/david) commented, it is straightforward to show that

[image]

so you can use standard methods to solve the problem with *A'* and *b'* and then transpose the answer.

Comment: This does not answer the non-negative aspect of the question

Comment: Of course it does. The OP already said that they have found functions like `lsqnonneg` and `lsqlin` which solve `A*x=b` with non-negative constraints, and this answer shows how to transform the problem to that form.